# Can I pull content from a specific webpage in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm looking to create a simple iOS app that displays the current water level of a local lake. The water level is updated daily on a specific URL. Is it possible to pull content from a webpage using objective c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Check out the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i).  From that link:

> The URL loading system provides support for accessing resources using the following protocols:
>
> - File Transfer Protocol (**`ftp://`**)
> - Hypertext Transfer Protocol (**`http://`**)
> - Secure 128-bit Hypertext Transfer Protocol (**`https://`**)
> - Local file URLs (**`file:///`**)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Use the NSURLConnection object. Use something like the function below, just pass an empty string for 'data' and then parse the HTML returned to find the value you're looking for.

```
-(void)sendData:(NSString*)data toServer:(NSString*)url{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSData *postData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(conn){
        //Connection successful
    }
    else{
        //Connection Failed
    }

    [conn release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier way yet using threading:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self contentsOfWebPage:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"] callback:^(NSString *contents) {
        NSLog(@"Contents of webpage => %@", contents);
    }];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void) contentsOfWebPage:(NSURL *) _url callback:(void (^) (NSString *contents)) _callback {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_url];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            _callback([[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

        });

    });
}
```